# Deletion won't halt even though 'return false' runs

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit, confirm

I have implemented the functionality to remove users from the database in my application. A user chooses user(s) (checkboxes) and clicks submit. A confirmation box is shown asking the user if he wants to delete *username*. Everything works except that if Cancel is clicked the user(s) still gets removed.

Why is that and how could I prevent it (I have check and **return false** runs)

**from usercontroller.php:**

```
if ($userView->TriedToRemoveUser()) {
  $userIds = $userView->GetUsersToRemove();

  if ($userIds != 0) {
    $removeTry = $userHandler->RemoveUser($userIds);

    if ($removeTry) {
      $xhtml = \View\UserView::USER_REMOVED;
    }
    else {
      $xhtml = \View\UserView::FAILED_TO_REMOVE_USER;
    }
  }
}
```

**from userview.php:**

```
public function TriedToRemoveUser() {
  if (isset($_POST[$this->_submitRemove])) {
    return true;        
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
}
```

**from the js.file:**

```
$('#form3').submit(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if( this.checked ) {
      var username = $(this).attr('user');

      var confirmBox = confirm('Do you really want to remove the user ' + username + ' ?');

      if (!confirmBox) {
        return false;
      }
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that a request is still made even though `return false;` runs in the javascript or that the PHP code still executes even though `$userView->TriedToRemoveUser()` returns false?

Comment: I mean that the submit request is still made even though return false. However, Kevin B's answer below solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(WARNING: All code is off the top of my head and not properly tested)

Assuming you are talking about the `return false;` statement in the javascript:

The `return false;` will not prevent the submit method as it is only breaking from the `.each()` method.  All this will do is stop the iteration over the checkboxes.

Try something like:

```
$('#form3').submit(function () {
    var doDelete = true;

    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
       // ...

       if (!confirmBox) {
           doDelete = false;
           return false; // Deletion has been cancelled so there is no need to continue the iteration
       }
    });

    if (!doDelete) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

This will prevent the entire form from being submitted if the user cancels any of the selected users.  If you're intention is to continue to submit any confirmed users you could try something like the following:

```
$('#form3').submit(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
       // ...

       if (!confirmBox) {
           $(this).attr('checked', false); //Uncheck this box so that it isn't submitted
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The last one was exactly what I was after and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Returning `false` from the `.each()` does not stop the submit, store that value in a variable and return that variable.

```
$('#form3').submit(function() {
    var submit = true;
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if( this.checked ) {
            var username = $(this).attr('user');

            var confirmBox = confirm('Do you really want to remove the user ' + username + ' ?');

            if (!confirmBox) {
                submit = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    return submit;
});
```

Comment: An alternative is to use a for or while loop, which would allow you to remove the additional variable and simply return false.